# Rails ajax form syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

What is the difference in below 2 Rails ajax forms.

Form 1

```
<%= form_tag '/posts', remote: true do %>

<% end -%>
```

Form 2

```
<%= form_tag ('/posts', remote: true) do %>

<% end -%>
```

While Form 1 works without any problem the form with parenthesis (Form 2) cause the below syntax error when trying to view the page in browser.

```
/home/my_app/app/views/articles/new.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...er.append=  form_tag ('/posts', remote: true) do @output_buf...
...                               ^
/home/my_app/app/views/articles/new.html.erb:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

I am using Rails 4.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, i also suffered this problem. For some reason removing the space after `form_for` method worked for me. So, this both will work.

```
 <%= form_tag('/posts', remote: true) do %>
```

and

```
 <%= form_tag '/posts', remote: true do %>
```

Comment: Yes. This worked for me. But I cannot find why it does not work with space. In general Ruby will allow that space after the method name even though it may not be quite the Ruby practice.

Comment: i guess that probably due to  `html.erb` to ruby parsing error.